# Errors encountered during git add operation

Tags: git

Everyone,

I am working with the Windows 7 command line (where I issue my git commands). 
Starting with an existing codebase contained within a directory called "externalprinter2", I enter this directory and give the following commands..

```
git init
git add .
```

After doing this, I get the following output..

```
Z:\Java\externalprinterjob2>git init
Initialized empty Git repository in Z:/Java/externalprinterjob2/.git/

Z:\Java\externalprinterjob2>git add .
Rename from '.git/objects/22/tmp_obj_lDzGrc' to '.git/objects/22/0c1c2cdfc67b69cd7b97f6d1a94f5743e0a976' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) n

error: unable to write sha1 filename .git/objects/22/0c1c2cdfc67b69cd7b97f6d1a94f5743e0a976: Permission denied

error: .DS_Store: failed to insert into database

error: unable to index file .DS_Store

fatal: adding files failed
```

Not sure how to proceed and would appreciate help from the git experts out there.

Comment: Now ... why the java tag?

Comment: `.DS_Store` should probably be included in your `.gitignore` as it has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: Looks like problems with directory permissions.

Comment: @GhostCat It was an error on my part.

Comment: @crashmstr I've added a .gitignore file in my worktree home directory.

Comment: @AdamByrtek I'm using Git Bash to change permissions with chmod, but the permissions don't change.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the command line into admin mode. If it does not work, may be your user does not have rights over those folders.

Comment: I'm running Git Bash in admin mode, and tried to change the folder permissions but the permissions didn't change. Git Bash is running a Linux  command line to access and modify permissions of directories created in Windows, not sure if that has something to do with the permissions not changing.